# Handing errors originating in Application_Start of ASP.NET MVC 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, error-handling, custom-error-pages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to handle ASP.NET application error that occurs on application start and transfer & display error in MVC view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407563/how-to-handle-asp-net-application-error-that-occurs-on-application-start-and-tra)

We are currently handling errors in an ASP.NET MVC 2 application using HandleError attribute in BaseController.

Web.config's custom error section is given below, which works fine handling all unhandled exceptions originating from Controllers

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="error.aspx">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/error/not-found"/>
</customErrors>
```

Error.aspx is placed under /Views/Shared folder which is a View inheriting from HandleErrorInfo

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="ViewPage<HandleErrorInfo>" %>
```

We have following code in Application_Start event handler of Global.asax

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    ValueProviderFactories.Factories.Add(new JsonValueProviderFactory());
    Bootstrapper.Initialize();
    ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new CustomControllerFactory(logger));
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

Bootstrapper.Initialize() is throwing some error while configuring a Structuremap registries. This errors won't invoke Error.aspx specified in web.config but I'll have to handle them separately using Application_Error event handler.

What is the best way to show same error.aspx for errors raised outside of normal ASP.NET MVC pipeline?