# Quickest place in mvc application to check if connection string is valid

Tags: asp.net-mvc

The customer wants to know if a connection string is valid, and display a friendly error page accordingly. I found the following code for that:

```
bool isValidConnectionString = true;

try
{
    var con = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cs"].ConnectionString);
}
catch (Exception)
{
    isValidConnectionString = false;
}
```

Now the question becomes, where to put this code, and how do I show an error page from that location?

I figured the best place would be to place this is soon as the application starts up, and that's in `Application_Start()`. But of course, here is not the best place to return a View.

So where would the best place be?

Comment: That *is* the best place - if you can't do anything without a database, there's no much point in setting up roots and views. You can redirect everything to the error page.

Comment: Why? This is one of those things you just set right and then forget it. You especially shouldn't let the user in on the fact that you bumbled something like a connection string to a database.

Comment: @ChrisPratt this is a valid request, *especially* when you deploy an application on a customer's or hosted environment. That's why all CMS products have a status/heartbeat page that shows whether all configuration steps are OK. Same with cloud providers and their dashboards. A few hours ago SO itself had a few minutes of downtime and displayed a "Back soon" page

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, indeed, it is something like that! The client whom I work for has some sort of CMS application that gets deployed to clients.

Comment: In this case you can redirect everything to a `Back Soon` page. You could also add a separate set of routes for troubleshooting, but you'd have to find a way to secure them. If you use the database to store credentials, you won't be able to authenticate the administrators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the database connection being proper, it is not very useful to setup the views and other stuff as mentioned by **@Panagiotis Kanavos**.

So the best place to find **this error** is `Application_Start()` itself as you've mentioned.

Since Application_Start() initializes the route table, RedirectToRoute or RedirectToAction are wrong choices.

---

### **updated answer**

**The best way to deal with this issue is:**

1. declare a global variable(Flag variable) to show if there is error.
2. use `try/catch` and, in the **catch** block, log the error.
3. Assign the global variable to indicate there is an error.

Now in `Application_BeginRequest()`, you could check if there is any error from Application_Start() by **check**ing the **global variable.** **If error is found**, do the necessary, like a **redirect with the error message in a session**. (here, session works.)

this answer has a reference from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2407610/6170109).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah! This is good. Though for some reason I can't use TempData and RedirectToRoute in Aplication()_Start(). I only have TempDictionaryData and RedirectToRouteResult, and even those won't work.

Comment: @AyatollahOfRockNRolla [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2407610/6170109) will be of help to you.

Answer (score 0):

Global.asax

```
Application_BeginRequest()
{ 
    try
    {
       var con = new  SqlConnectionStringBuilder(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cs"].ConnectionString);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
       // redirect client browser .html friendly error page 
    }
}
```

Be carefull

BeginRequest could be triggered for all requests (including static content) you have to manage this circumstance.